# Running Rcpp code chunk aborting R session

Tags: c++, r, for-loop, rcpp, abort

The R session is terminating by saying that a fatal error is occurred. I have little knowledge in C++ and Rcpp and I have no clue what is the source of the problem.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
 NumericVector cumyRes(double a, double b, double timedt, NumericVector dt, 
                       NumericVector ProbMDset, NumericVector MainMDset, 
                       NumericVector decPoints, double LP, double LT,
                       double p1, double pA, int ii, double x1, double x2){
  bool repFlag = false;
  int n = dt.size();
  double inity = 0;
  NumericVector out(n);
  std::unordered_set<double> sampleSetMd(MainMDset.begin(), MainMDset.end());
  std::unordered_set<double> sampleSetProb(ProbMDset.begin(), ProbMDset.end());
  std::unordered_set<double> sampleSetDec(decPoints.begin(), decPoints.end());
  
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
    ii = ii + 1;
    double d = dt[ii];
    out[ii] = inity + rgamma(1, a * timedt, b)[0];
    inity = out[ii];
    
    if (sampleSetDec.find(d) != sampleSetDec.end()) {
        if (sampleSetProb.find(d + LT) != sampleSetProb.end() ||
            sampleSetMd.find(d + LT) != sampleSetMd.end()) {
          repFlag = inity >= LP;
        } else if (sampleSetMd.find(d) != sampleSetMd.end() && repFlag) {
          double genRanProb = rbinom(1, 1, (1 - p1))[0];
          for (int j = ii; ii < (ii+x1); ++j){
            out[j] = inity * genRanProb;
          }
          inity = inity * genRanProb;
          ii = ii + x1 - 1;
        } else if (sampleSetProb.find(d) != sampleSetProb.end() && repFlag) {
          double genRanProb = rbinom(1, 1, pA)[0];
          for (int j = ii; ii < (ii+x2); ++j){
            out[j] = inity * genRanProb;
          }
          inity = inity * genRanProb;
          ii = ii + x2 - 1;
        }}}
  return out;
}")
```

Comment: "I have no clue what is the source of the problem." -- a good debugging rule is to make your problem smaller and try to solve each sub-problem. Also, `Rcpp` has a tag here (unsurprisingly also `rcpp`) so you get search among the over 2900 answers we have accumulated under it.

Comment: These types of "R Session Aborting" errors typically come from "index out of range" errors. That is, trying to access an element of an index that doesn't exist. As Dirk says you need to make your problem(s) smaller and debug a lne or two at a time. As a starting point, focus on those lines where you access a vector element with `[0]`, `[j]` or `[ii]` etc. Make sure those vectors acually have data in them at the correct position

Comment: This seems to be a great clue as I also have reasons to believe that this is probably the case. I will get back with an update after I try it.

Answer (score 2):

Would need to see the error to be totally sure this is the only issue. But there are several issues here with type casting.

> `for (int j = ii; ii < (ii+x1); ++j)`

You declared `double x1` and `int ii` this will not work as you are trying to implicitly cast `ii` as `double`

A little further down you have

> `ii = ii + x1 - 1;`

Once again you are trying to implicitly cast an `int` as `double`

Same with

> `for (int j = ii; ii < (ii+x2); ++j){`

and

> `ii = ii + x2 - 1;`

TL;DR - C++ is a STATICALLY typed language. These kind of implicit type conversions are not going to work.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, however, it is probably not the issue as the problem persists even after changing x1 and x2 to int as well.